# error building phonegap application : Error installing local npm package

Tags: node.js, cordova, phonegap-cli

I use visual studio 2015 to create a mobile app using javascript apache cordova app. but when I want to build it , I got two errors:

> Error installing local npm package.

and this error :

> Could not find module 'C:\Users\rayban pc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\app.js'. Please Go to Tools --> Options --> Tools for Apache Cordova --> Cordova Tools --> Clear Cordova Cache and try building again

I clear cache , but error occur again. 
I set environment variables for android sdk , java , ant and node.js correctly.
please help me solve this error.

Answer (score 0):

What update of TACO are you on? Earlier versions of TACO sometimes have npm and Node versioning issues. Update to the latest version (VS15, Update 8) http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/release-update-8/, which sandboxes Node and npm. After you update, try to build a new blank project.

Answer (score 0):

My Problem Solve when I update my android sdk and get all version of sdk.